# Pythonic way of packing an object and 2 lists into a single iterable?

Tags: python

Working on an asteroids game, and I want to check for out of bonds on all my entities in a single loop.

Is

```
for entity in itertools.chain([ship], bullets, asteroids):
   ...
```

The best way to do so?

Comment: Seems fine to me. I'd probably use a 1-tuple though.

Comment: Looks good to me, should have low overhead compared to most alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without going into defining "Pythonic", the code is concise and quite readable/understandable.

Also, since you're just iterating over existing data structures without any copying, efficiency should be quite good.